# Sample weights interpretation

Tags: sampling, survey, survey-weights, survey-sampling

The sample followed a two-stage design. In the first stage the primary sampling units (enumarating areas, EA) were randomly selected. In the second stage, in each EA, 10 secondary sampling units (households) were randomly selected. Every household in the sample is weighted. The weight indicates the number of households in the population represented by the household in the sample.

Does this weight accounts for both strata and primary sampling units?

Answer (score 0):

There is no telling, based on your question, how the weights are constructed.

Generally, weights accommodate the basic counting rules that are responsible for the estimates being consistent for their population targets. They correct for informative sampling when different units with different characteristics of interest may have different probabilities of selection and response, either by design (certain units are intentionally oversampled) or by the nature of the population (households that can be reached on landline/fixed line phones are usually older and less mobile than those that can be reached on cell phones, at least in the U.S.). Strata and primary sampling units, on the other hand, are responsible for correct variance estimation. So they have rather different functions in survey design and analysis with complex survey data. Please see references in [survey-weights](/questions/tagged/survey-weights) for additional explanations.